# Maven Enforce some rules on pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

So here is the problem that I have, I want to ban users from having local repositories in their pom.xml. I could probably do it with the enforcer plugin, but at the same time nothing is stopping someone from deleting the plugin and running the project without it. It would be very cool if there were a way to have these enforcement placed in settings.xml or may be extend maven somehow.

The general idea is that I would like users to still run the same "clean install" and if there are local repositories configured in pom.xml, the project should fail.

Is that even possible with maven?

**EDIT**
To keep it simple: when I run "mvn clean install" against a pom that has repositories configured inside it, the build must fail. Notice that I do not want to use some sort of plugin to achieve that, unless it can be configured with settings.xml for example.
Why do I want that? Because it messes up the automatic builds in our case, external repositories must be configured in settings.xml and not locally in each pom.

Comment: What users and what POMs? More details about your use case, please.

Comment: So if the hypothetical user is going to muck with the POM, what stops them from mucking with settings.xml?

Comment: @TomG the deployment machine (where the code runs) is totally under my control only, builds are automatically pushed to these machines, without user interaction at all. No way someone can edit setting.xml there.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a technical fix to a cultural problem. If developers are modifying the build file incorrectly, you need to explain to them why they shouldn't do that (and why they shouldn't introduce third-party repos).

Comment: @TomG totally agree, if this were an option.

Comment: I just had a thought -- what if you configured this in a parent POM that the project POM inherits from? The parent POM would be in your controlled repo, and would not be editable.

Comment: @TomG you should put this is an answer, got me to my final solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up editing the maven Super pom in the jar file maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar. I added the enforcer plugin with no repositories rule. Seems to work fine. 
All with one simple script. Here is the script - could probably made better(I am by far not a scripting guru :) ):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #couple of safety checks
 if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then 
     echo "usage: ./maven-enforcer.sh <path_to_the_maven_install_lib_folder>"
     echo "1 argument required, $# provided"
     exit 1
 fi

 if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
     echo "directory '$1' does not exist, exiting..."
     exit 1
 fi

 if [ ! -e $1/maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar ]; then
      echo "file 'maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar' does not exist in directory $1, exiting..."
      exit 1
 fi

 #back-up the already existing jar
 cp $1/maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar $1/maven-model-builder-3.0.5_backup.jar

 cd $1

 #unpack the contents of the jar
 jar xf $1/maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar

 cd org/apache/maven/model/

 #test if the command did not run already
 didItRunAlready=`grep -n "maven-enforcer-plugin" pom-4.0.0.xml | cut -f1 -d:`

 if [[ ! -z "$didItRunAlready" ]]; then
    echo "Command already run once, exiting..."
    exit 1
 fi

 lineNumber=`grep -n "</pluginManagement>" pom-4.0.0.xml | cut -f1 -d:`

 textToAdd="<plugins>\n<plugin>\n<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>\n<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>\n<version>1.3.1</version>\n<executions>\n<execution>\n<id>enforce-no-repositories</id>\n<goals>\n<goal>enforce</goal>\n</goals>\n<configuration>\n<rules>\n<requireNoRepositories>\n<message>Best Practice is to never define repositories in pom.xml (use a repository manager instead)</message>\n</requireNoRepositories>\n</rules>\n</configuration>\n</execution>\n</executions>\n</plugin></plugins>"

 sed ""$lineNumber"a $textToAdd" pom-4.0.0.xml > result.xml 
 rm pom-4.0.0.xml
 mv result.xml pom-4.0.0.xml

 cd ../../../../

 jar vfu maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar org/

 rm -fr META-INF
 rm -fr org

 echo "Succesfully updated maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new pom module, which will execute ant task to validate your target pom.xml against required x-path.